# DropDuplicates in PySpark gives stackoverflowerror

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a PySpark program which reads a json files of size around 350-400 MB and created a dataframe out of it.

In my next step, I create a Spark SQL query using `createOrReplaceTempView` and select few columns as required

Once this is done, I filter my dataframe with some conditions. It was working fine until this point of time.

Now, I needed to remove some duplicate values using a column. So, I introduced,
 `dropDuplicates` in next step and it suddenly started giving me `StackoverflowError`

Below is the sample code:-

```
def create_some_df(initial_df):
    initial_df.createOrReplaceTempView('data')
    original_df = spark.sql('select c1,c2,c3,c4 from data')

## Filter out some events
    original_df = original_df.filter(filter1condition)
    original_df = original_df.filter(filter2condition)
    original_df = original_df.dropDuplicates(['c1'])
    return original_df
```

It worked fine until I added dropDuplicates method.
I am using 3 node AWS EMR cluster `c5.2xlarge`

I am running PySpark using `spark-submit` command in YARN `client` mode

**What I have tried**

I tried adding `persist` and `cache` before calling filter, but it didn't help

**EDIT  - Some more details**

I realise that the error appears when I invoke my write function after multiple transformation i.e first action.
If I have `dropDuplicates` in my transformation before I write, it fails with error.

If I do *not* have `dropDuplicates` in my transformation, write works fine.

Comment: Try not to use the same Dataframe name repeatedly. Dataframes are immutable.

Comment: @neil why can't we write filter condition in Spark-SQL--- that is not an issue can you please add c1,c2,c3,c4 data for more understanding and applying above step.

Comment: c1,c2,c3,c4 are all text based columns. No specific reason to not add filter in SQL. I already have few filter conditions in there, just trying to split it up for easier debugging

Comment: @Neil, can you please paste the entire error message if possible?